# How to migrate Sonar from Maven to Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am migrating a Maven project that uses the sonar maven plugin to Gradle (plugin ver 3.2 / sonar server ver 5.1.2)

I assumed that I need the [sonarqube gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube). Of the bat there are two issues

1. The latest (and apparently only) version is compatible with sonar 5.6
2. For some reason the plugin wants to establish a jdbc connection although the sonar server is running on a remote machine and the sonar maven plugin
   was able to operate without a local DB

Comment: The current version of SonarQube is 6.5 and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a hard time finding support for any version prior to that.

Comment: So there is no way to have a Gradle build use Sonar 5.1 ? Even with an older version of a Gradle plugin?

Comment: Actually, here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle it is stated that "he SonarQube Scanner for Gradle version 2.0 is compatible with Gradle versions 1.12+ and SonarQube versions 4.5+." However Gradle is unable to resolve the dependency on 2.0